# How can i toggle a Boolean value correctly for specific object in a array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a toggle that shows me the edit item modal when I click the button, but when I click it, it opens all the modals.

I have tried to make the state as an object but it has not worked for me.

[image: Here is the image where you can see an a issue]

```
   state = {
         fotosSelected: [],
         editModalShowHide: false,
   }
```

OpenEditModal button is defined in a map function below.

```
  OpenEditModal = () => {
    this.setState({
    editModalShowHide: !this.state.editModalShowHide,
  });
 };


 handleChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
    fotosSelected: [...this.state.fotosSelected, ...e.target.files],
  });
}

selectedFiles = () => {
return this.state.fotosSelected?.map((value, index) => {
  // console.log(value);
  if (value?.name != null || value?.name != undefined) {
    return (
      <div className="eachFileSelected" key={value.name}>
        <div className="checkBoxMoreOption">
          <button onClick={() => this.OpenEditModal(value.name, index)}>
            <MoreVertIcon />
          </button>
        </div>
        {this.state.editModalShowHide[index]?.selected ? (
          <div className="editFileNameModal">
            <EditIcon />
            <span>Editar</span>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}
      </div>
      );
    }
  });
};

return = () => {
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
      multiple
      id="fileInput"
      ></input>
    {this.selectedFiles()}
}
```

Comment: You have only one `editModalShowHide` controlling the edit button. You need to add that property to each object inside `fotosSelected` array. Like the `name` property.

Comment: You don't show how you populate `fotosSelected`.

Comment: As you can see I have added more code above, where i added how i add files to fotosSelected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to edit one item at a time (open one modal at a time), you can control the modal's show/hide state by its index. For example `editModalShowIndex` instead of `editModalShowHide`. Then indicate that `-1` means all the modals should be hidden. And `n` means that modal of item with index `n` should be shown.

```
state = {
  fotosSelected: [],
  editModalShowIndex: -1,
};

OpenEditModal = (_, index) => {
  this.setState({
    editModalShowIndex: this.state.editModalShowIndex === -1 ? index : -1,
  });
};

this.state.fotosSelected?.map((value, index) => {
  <Modal open={editModalShowIndex === index} />
}
```